# Locally Lipschitz $H^1$ and $L_{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have a doubt.
Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and the function $f:H^1{\Omega}\to L_{2}(\Omega)$ defined by $f(u)=-|u|^{p-1}u$. I have to proof that $f$ is locally lipschitz if $2p<p^*$,with $p=\frac{2n}{n-2}$. 
I try to derivative f, $f'(u)=-p|x|^{p-1}$ and show that $f'$ is bounded. however, I do not get to that condition $p ^ *$.

I think existe to some property between $H^1(\Omega)$ to $L_{2}(\Omega)$.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: The Sobolev embedding theorem asserts the continuous inclusion $H^1\to L^q$ for $n>2$ and $2\le q\le 2n/(n-2)$. This is a restriction on $f$. Good luck!

Comment: thx, very useful